# Array range within a range of only chosen numbers PHP

Tags: php

I am a a beginner and i made this:

```
<?php

$numbers = range(1, 100);

shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number . " ";


}

?>
```

I thought i could make it work with the out commented code but i don't know what to do anymore after searching so much online, i thought i could copy it(for) and make it work but it copied the same shuffle range instead of separate shuffle numbers.

I want the range from 1 until 100 with numbers only between 1 and 6. That's it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you want array with __100__ numbers between 1 and 6?

Comment: Yes i want the array between 1 and 100 but the numbers inside 100 can only contain numbers between 1 and 6

Comment: So create a loop and add a random value between 1 and six to array.

Comment: I want  562141241246124641241246242144612414124612412461241242141: 100 numbers. It can't be above 6(1-6) inside that 100 range

Comment: I added a loop (as you can see is commented out inside my code) but if you use a loop the 6 numbers just multiply without having the shuffle function. So how can i imply the shuffle at every increase level forloop until 10 times

Comment: You should change the title to this question. People searching for the same problem will not be able to tell what this question is about by only reading your title.

Comment: I will change the title

Comment: I am sorry for this but i am now busy with practicing and i was wondering if i have to array's, so the one you made + a copy of that. How can i make a third array that counts up every value together from array1 and array2. So if array1 = 1,5,6,7 and array2 = 2,6,4,8 then array 3 should be = 3,11,10,15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple loop adding 100 random values to array:

```
$random_ints = [];
while (count($random_ints) < 100) {
    $random_ints[] = random_int(1, 6);
    // or 
    // $random_ints[] = mt_rand(1, 6);
}
echo implode($random_ints);
```

Comment: It's that simple ha? haha Thankyou

Comment: I am sorry for this but i am now busy with practicing and i was wondering if i have to array's, so the one you made + a copy of that. How can i make a third array that counts up every value together from array1 and array2. So if array1 = 1,5,6,7 and array2 = 2,6,4,8 then array 3 should be = 3,11,10,15